# Three.js Loading Same Objects

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I want to load multiple objects with THREE OBJLoader. But I don't know how to do it. I'm using this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){  
loader.load('suzanne.obj', function(event) {
    var object = event;
    object.traverse(function(child) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material.map = texture;
        }
    });
    object.position.set(3 * i, 0.5,3);
    scene.add(object);
}); }
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong but it had to be something with async loading objects... I should wait for object to load then add it to scene and then load next object,... How can I detect when object is loaded so I can proceed to next object?

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl3_performance.html

Comment: Do you want to load ten of the same object into the scene?