# Drawing a cube a million times

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I need to build terrain using one cube with dimensions 1x1x1, the coordinates are provided in a .txt file and there are about 11M triplets.

The problem is that using my current code I can only draw about 60k of them, then the browser tab is resetted and a prompt to stop an unresponsive script comes out, so I use too much memory and time to generate them.

Here is the chunk of code I use to draw them:

```
function generateCubes(data) {
    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x587058});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
    var mergedGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
    var instance;
    var line = data[0].split(';');
    var translateX = line[0], translateY = line[1], translateZ = line[2];
    //var group = new THREE.Object3d();
    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { // should go to data.length
        line = data[i].split(';');
        //instance = mesh.clone();
        //instance.position.set(line[0] - translateX, line[2] - translateZ, line[1] - translateY);
        //group.add(instance);
        mesh.position.x = Number(line[0]) - translateX;
        mesh.position.y = Math.round(Number(line[2]) - translateZ);
        mesh.position.z = Number(line[1]) - translateY;
        mesh.updateMatrix();
        mergedGeo.merge(instance.geometry, instance.matrix);
    }
    group = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeo, material);
    scene.add(group);
}
```

The function is called from a success in an $.ajax call.

The commented parts are used without merged geometry, that way I can draw around 100k of the data.

Thank you for helping me.

EDIT: I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931070/display-several-times-the-same-3d-object-with-three-js) and it did not help me much.

Comment: you should look at this example: http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot draw 11M objects with individual draw calls even from c++. Take a look at [instancing](http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is voxel rendering. Two main rendering paths to accomplish this: A) volume rendering, but webgl lack hardware 3d textures support. B) mesh surface generation and standard polygon rendering. Probably the only option you have. Dont think there is any good efficient js implementation in public yet.

What you need to do.

1. Divide your world into chunks of the same dimension, chunk
   dimensions probably needs to be power of 2 to allow for faster
   operations on them.
2. Come up with a data structure that can store your 11M voxel data.
   This probably need to be in some arrangement of Int32Arrays and use
   bit wise operators to access/store data on each voxel.
3. For each chunk, generate the surface mesh. See [link](http://0fps.net/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/).
4. For chunks that are far from camera, come up with some scheme where you
   can generate meshes of low LOD (optional).
5. Render all chunks in your visible frustum in a front to back
   order.

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of efficient is but there's certainly plenty of webgl minecraft clones. Googling "minecraft webgl" brought up [this library](http://voxeljs.com/) and [this example](http://benvanik.github.io/blk-game/) and tons of others.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How should the data structure look like? I thought it could be a large MxN polygon which is 1 block thick, since I am building a terrain which looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/7ZsanUp.png) with 60k cubes 
@gman I saw voxeljs, but I do not know how can I build a custom terrain using my data, even though it would be perfect if I could, any help?

Comment: @gman It not difficult to display multiple static mesh that appears to be composed of cubes. You can find minecraft "clones" on shadertoy for less than 200 lines of code but that doesnt mean it you can extend it and have the same capabilities as minecraft.

Comment: @Mark I store each chunk as a Uint32Array of size chunkDimension ^3 (cubed). Then the position of each voxels is implicitly stored based on its index in the chunk. This saves a ton of memory as a world position x,y,z would ordinarily require 3 floats and thus at least 12 bytes.

Comment: @WacławJasper so, if I understood correctly, the each voxel is positioned where my data is, and then a set of voxels are chunks, right? So, in the data structure I store where each voxel is placed? I am not sure if I understood what you wrote, please explain.

Comment: @WaclawJasper, I'm not sure what you're getting at. Those samples are not any more static than minecraft itself. Both demos I linked to are fully modifiable at runtime. There's no reason you couldn't run all of minecraft in JavaScript. A computer's a computer's a computer. Even If you have to use emscripten (which I doubt you would), it's still JavaScript.

Comment: @gman The OP need to render 11M voxels. As terrain. Probably with unspecified additional requirements. If you can demonstrate how to do this with one of the tool you linked, I am sure OP will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: 11M voxels is not a large world. That's only 223^3 size world. Voxel.js and pretty much any other JS voxel engine would have no problem with such a small world.

Comment: @gman I do not know how to generate the world with voxeljs, since I only have the coordinates of the cubes in the terrain and the generator requires some kind of an equation as far as I saw, and I have no intention of converting them into .mca in order to read them like that.

Comment: @Mark, `game.setBlock(pos, 1)` creates a voxel or load your data and write a function that `generate` can use to look into your data [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/u5kzvj4c/)

Comment: thank you a lot @gman, it's a great starting point. I will give it a try and I will write here if I need any advise

Comment: @gman yo welccome, was tryng to find u, basically how can one make a voxel world with mergin? because once its all merged then how can one edit it later? are boolean operators fesasible?